# How can I prevent more than a set number of users from accessing a visual force page?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have a situation where I only want a set number of users to access a Visual Force page concurrently. For e.g., I have 10 users and only want 3 people to access the VF page at the same time.

Is this possible in visual Force?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Mind explaining the business case ? Sounds pretty tricky.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom Settings for this.
When a user open the page you record his id in some CS by constructor. 
and by JS (window.onbeforeunload) and @RemoteAction before user close page delete id from CS.

Answer (score 0):

By "accessing the page at the same time", do you mean not more than 3 people can have the page open in a browser window? If so, that is just not possible via pure Visualforce. You would have to overcome the limitations of HTML which is a stateless protocol.